# Difference between "hypnotic" and "hypnotizing"

Tags: differences, adjectives, present-participles

Is there a difference between *hypnotic* and *hypnotizing*? I believe they are synonyms but I think of *hypnotic* as being more metaphorical, and *hypnotizing* as being used, at least sometimes, as a clinical (or at least factual, non-metaphorical) term.

Comment: Please see [this Meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/asking-questions-about-synonyms) and in particular [JR's answer there](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3494/18696) for hints on how to help this question to stay open and how you can avoid further downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hypnotic" is a standard adjective, while "hypnotizing" is an adjective that has been created out of a verb, which is called a "participle adjective".

What that means, is that something that has the potential to induce hypnosis (literal or figurative) would be considered "hypnotic", whereas something that is "hypnotizing" is currently in the process of hypnotizing (in the verb sense, figuratively or literally) something.

> His gaze was hypnotic.

The above phrase indicates a quality in a person's gaze, in that it has the potential to entrance someone.

> His gaze was hypnotizing.

This phrase, on the other hand, indicates that the narrator (or the character in context) is actually caught in the trap, entranced by the hypnotic gaze — or rather, that the gaze is in the process of entrancing the narrator.

There is no real reason why one should be considered more metaphorical than the other, although it could be argued that "hypnotizing" is the more common term in the literal sense, simply because it is easier to factually identify an action, rather than a vague property. Whether or not that is the case, I do not know — in truth, I always thought that "hypnotic" was the more common word.

Comment: You are quite right that _hypnotic_ is the more commonly-used word, according to [Google NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hypnotic%2C+hypnotizing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)